# Que hace esta linea de codigo

Tags: java, netbeans-11.3

```
private static void listanormal() {
    int cantidadperson=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Coloca la cantidad de personas que estaran"));
    String listap[]=new String[cantidadperson];
    for(int i=0;i<listap.length;i++){
        listap[i]=new String(); // <- esta es la que no entiendo que hace
        listap[i]=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un nombre");
    }
    System.out.println("Aqui estaria su listado de personas que pidio");
    for(int i=0;i<listap.length;i++){
        System.out.println(listap[i]);
    }
```

Comment: crea un objeto String vacío.

Answer (score 1):

A ver si puedo explicar:

```
    //aquí, se crea una variable de enteros, donde se almacena el número de valores que tendrá el array de personas
    int cantidadperson = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Coloca la cantidad de personas que estaran"));
    //Aquí se declara el array de personas dando como tamaño el valor de la varible anterior.
    String[] listap = new String[cantidadperson];
    //bucle que tendrá de iteraciones el tamaño del array
    for (int i = 0; i < listap.length; i++) {
        //En ésta línea se crea un string vacío en cada posición del array. No es algo aconsejado, pues usando new, lo que se hace es crear también un espacio en memoria, que además en éste caso estará vacío. Esta línea se podría suprimir.
        //La gran diferencia es que si la eliminamos y no damos valores al contenido del array, en cada posición del mismo nos arrojará null, y con ésta línea nos arrojaría una línea en blanco.
        listap[i] = new String(); 
        //en ésta línea nos va pidiendo un nombre que almacenará en cada posición del array
        listap[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un nombre");
    }
    //aquí imprimimos en una línea el texto mostrado entre paréntesis
    System.out.println("Aqui estaria su listado de personas que pidio");
    //ésto bucle recorrerá el array
    for(int i = 0; i < listap.length; i++) {
        //en cada iteración del bucle imprimirá el valor del array contenido en esa posición
        System.out.println(listap[i]);
    }
```

Para comprender mejor la línea que no estiendes, te propongo unas pruebas

Primero ejecutas el código completo para que veas su funcionamiento. Te pide la longitud del array y luego un nombre para cada dicha posición

Una vez lo hayas probado, comentas ésta parte:

```
//listap[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un nombre");
```

Ahora se ejecutará el programa, te pedirá el número de posiciones del array, pero no te pedirá ningún valor para esas posiciones, y verás que se imprimirán tantas líneas en blanco como número has indicado en la longitud del array. Cada línea en blanco representará ese string vacío de la línea anterior.

La siguiene prueba sería comentando las dos líneas del bucle

```
//listap[i] = new String();      
//listap[i] = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Ingresa un nombre");
```

Ahora verás que se ejecutará el programa, te pedirá el número de valores del array y al imprimir dichos valores, te arojará el valor null en cada fila, pues aún no hemos introducido ningún valor en cada posición del array.